# Zendesk and Smooch integration

Tags: zendesk, smooch

I've integrated my smooch account with Zendesk. But when I write a message to a chat, smooch creates a new anonymous user in Zendesk. Is there a way to bind a smooch user to already created one in Zendesk?

Comment: Speaking as someone who is familiar with zendesk and smooch (disclaimer I work @ Smooch), it's actually perfectly clear what he's trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no it is not currently possible to bind a Smooch user with an existing Zendesk user.

However, depending on how you are using Smooch you can pre-fill basic profile information, for example first and last name. If you're using any of the Smooch SDKs (web, ios, android) you can do this via those SDK APIs, E.g: https://docs.smooch.io/guide/native-ios-sdk/

You also have the option to assign your Smooch users a userId which can be used to identify a user across multiple devices or channels. It's optional, but if you choose to do this you can pre-create the user record in Smooch as a way to pre-fill profile information that would show up in Zendesk.

https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#operation/createUser

Answer (score 1):

[2022 Update]

To paraphrase the page on [Authenticating end-users in the Messaging web/mobile SDKs](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4411666638746-Authenticating-end-users-in-messaging-for-the-Web-Widget-and-mobile-SDK#topic_yfv_qqx_3sb):

If the `external_id` in a Zendesk user's profile (set [via Tickets API](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/users/users/#json-format)), matches the `external_id` provided in the JWT (used to log the user in to the SDK), then any resulting ticket from that user's conversation(s) will be linked to the matching Zendesk user.

(this applies to the Messaging web & mobile SDKs, and also the Sunshine Conversations web & mobile SDKs)

[2021 Update]

Since the launch of the new Zendesk Suite with Agent Workspace (and the Smooch acquisition before that), comes a brand-new *Sunshine Conversations* integration and new features when using the [Switchboard](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/switchboard/#switchboard).

Basically, you can set a middleware (or 3rd-party system) as your `defaultSwitchboardIntegration`, which could:

- receive all net-new conversations (before users/tickets are created in ZD),
- determine the user's email (internal DB, ZD user lookup, etc.)
- `passControl` to Zendesk, so that a ticket is opened

  - include the the user's email in the metadata, in the format:   `"dataCapture.systemField.requester.email": "<user email>"`

Upon receiving this new ticket, the new integration will perform a lookup. of the provided email against all users in the ZD User DB, and auto-associate on match (instead of creating a new user record)

For more on Switchboard, and the full list of parameters that can be set via `passControl`. (incl. Tags, etc.), see the docs here: https://docs.smooch.io/guide/switchboard/#metadata-sent-to-zendesk